# Detecting suppressed auras

Tags: ars-magica-5

The various Realms of Power books describe how an aura can be suppressed by a stronger (or equal-level Divine) aura; but I can't see anything definitive that says that either:

- You can't detect the suppressed aura (until it ceases being suppressed)
- You can detect it, and here's how.

Can anyone provide a pointer to something I've missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To begin with some quotes:

RoP:D, p10 has this to say about Dominiating Divine Auras:

> More so than other auras, the
>   Dominion regularly conflicts and challenges the auras from other realms.
>   During the expansion of Christianity,
>   Islam, and the kingdom of Israel, the
>   Dominion abutted and pressed against
>   Magic and Faerie auras. Due to the purpose and nature of the Dominion, when it
>   comes to influence in an area with another realm’s aura of equal strength, the Dominion will trump the opposing aura; a more-powerful aura will still overwhelm
>   the Dominion, however.
>
> Exempli Gratia: A church with a
>   Dominion rating of 4 is built
>   upon an ancient pagan temple to
>   Pan with a Faerie aura of 4. The
>   Dominion will preside during
>   the day. At night (when the
>   Dominion decreases to 3) and
>   on holy days to Pan (when the
>   Faerie aura increases to 5), the
>   Faerie aura emerges.

Thus, the faerie aura doesn't *go away*, it just isn't influencing the world. While, over time, this will result in the creation of a faerie regione, depending on the nature of the faeries and the stories they are telling.

RoP:M p13:

> Magic regiones can also arise due to the
>   impingement of a stronger foreign aura, but
>   this is significantly rarer, at least for cov-
>   enants. The foreign aura compresses the
>   area of the Magic aura so strongly that the
>   Magic appears to vanish. Usually the Magic
>   aura has indeed vanished, but sometimes it
>   will instead move up into a regio, leaving the
>   lower level in contact with the foreign aura.

However, both of these are refinements and restatements of the core rules, p183:

> Two realms may have influence over the
>   same place. When this is the case, only the
>   stronger can hold sway at any one time. A
>   change in the relative strengths of the two
>   realms can cause an area to switch from the
>   influence of one to the other.

Therefore, there is no reason why the presiding of the divine dominion aura prevents detection via the ImVi 1 guidelines, save if God wills it. However, if we presume the aura is "eliminated" we can merely treat it much like negative magnitudes of spell residues (HoH:TL 74) and increase the magnitude of the effect needed to discover the aura.